# What is the Gundam anime and movies and OVA order?

Tags: gundam

There are a lot of Gundam anime series, movies and OVAs, so I don't know where to start.

**Can anyone tell me its order to watch it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 6 different accepted universes within the Gundam Multiverse.

Each has its own characters unique to its timeline, and does not intersect with any other timelines (ex: In Gundam Wing, the events from Mobile Suit Gundam never happened).

They are listed as follows:

**Universal Century Time line** (Best place to start to get into it, every single Gundam series out there is rooted in characters/gundam from this time line).
In order they are:

- Mobile Suit Gundam
- Mobile Suit Zeta Gundam
- Mobile Suit Gundam ZZ
- Char's Counterattack
- MS Gundam 0080: War in the Pocket MS
- Gundam F91 MS Gundam 0083: Stardust Memory
- MS Victory Gundam
- MS Gundam Unicorn.
- Turn A Gundam (This series is really good and is a huge shift in focus from prior gundams. Its set roughly 1000 years in the future, and Turn A is quite possibly the most powerful Gundam in the entire Gundam franchise).

**After Colony Timeline** This is probably where most people are introduced into the Gundam world. A group of space colony scientists build Gundams piloted by young boys in hopes of weakening Earths oppressive Government.

- Gundam Wing
- Endless Waltz

**Cosmic Era Timeline** If the Universal Century seems to "old" for your tastes, this is a great place to jump into Gundam.

- Gundam SEED
- Gundam SEED Destiny
- Gundam SEED MSV Astray
- Gundam SEED Stargazer

**After War Timeline** Welcome to your post apocalyptic Gundam universe. Basically the series take place after a giant colony is dropped on Earth, wiping out almos the entire population.

- Gundam X

**Future Century Timeline** Instead of giant wars and colonies fighting one another, rulers are decided by a Gundam tournament that occurs every 4 years.

- G Gundam

**Anno Domini Timeline** Several factions are constantly vying for power when a mysterious group known as Celestial Beings creates Gundams that are years beyond an current MS technology.

- Gundam 00

That concludes our journey through the very bumpy Gundam multiverse lane. I left out a few movies and tv specials, but I think I captured the bigger picture here. Now go forth, and become Gundam maesters!

The above was found [here](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Gundam_Wiki:Series).

Comment: Your UC does not appear to be in order, for example [according to another page in the wiki](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Universal_Century) 8th MS Team is UC0079 and far away from Unicorn in UC0096. I would also add *The Origin* and probably *Gundam Reconguista in G* to UC. There are also the *Advanced Generation* and *Post Disaster* (and [*Correct Century*](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Correct_Century)¿?) timelines, which you probably have missed. The page is really long. :\

Comment: It's difficult to know the exact order when different sources say different things :/